# D2DCanvas drawing bitmap with sourceRectangle

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, draw, direct2d

I have an issue with Direct2D when drawing bitmap while specifying source rectangle and hope someone can point me how to fix it.
I am following the example from here: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_the_Direct2D_Canvas

So basically I have a custom Direct2d accelerated control to paint a 256 x 256 bitmap on it.
When I just call

```
AcceleratedPaintPanel1.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(FBitmapToPaint);
```

the result is correct, the image drawn is 256 x 256 pixels.

But it is strange when I specify source rectangle, the second image is oversized! I set the source rectangle same size as the image (256 x 256) and dont see any reason why should it be  oversized.  This is just a simple example with one image, but what I need to do is to get different parts from the source image and draw them separately, but all methods that use source rectangle are drawing images oversized.
Thank you.

```
var
 D2D1RectF:TD2D1RectF;
begin
// Image 1 - properly sized image
AcceleratedPaintPanel1.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(FBitmapToPaint); 

   D2D1RectF.left:= 256;
   D2D1RectF.top:= 0;
   D2D1RectF.right:= 512;
   D2D1RectF.bottom:= 256;

// Image 2 - oversized 
AcceleratedPaintPanel1.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(FBitmapToPaint, @D2D1RectF);
```

[image]

Comment: Likely DPI scaling. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-high-dpi

Comment: If so, this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64182902/282848